# Custom MultiAutoCompleteTextView like Autocomplete result must suggest me  'ThankYou' when i type 'TY'

Tags: android

I am creating demo of simple `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`.

I have gone through the official docs [MultiAutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html). Completed this simple tutorial.

But this is something different than what i am trying to achieve.

What i want is :

When i type 'TY' then autocomplete result must suggest me 'Thank You'.

Such acronym and meaning pairs are stored in the database.

Ofcourse my acronym and meaning pairs are not many so storage is not a problem(can store in String Array too).

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I solved it by myselves :

I created Custom CursorAdapter. Using the object of my Custom CursorAdapter, i got desired results.

```
public static class MessageAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable 
    {
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

        public MessageAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) 
        {
            super(context, c);
            dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(context);
            dbHelper.open();
            mContent = context.getContentResolver();
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final TextView view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);
            view.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_MEANING)));
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
        {
            ((TextView) view).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_MEANING)));
        }

        @Override
        public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
            return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_MEANING));
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint)
        {
            if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null)
            {
                return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
            }

            StringBuilder buffer = null;
            String args = null;
            if (constraint != null) 
            {
                args=constraint.toString();             
            }
            Cursor newCursor=dbHelper.getMeaning(args);
            //You have to return results based on the above cursor results. So query whatver you want and return this cursor back.
            return newCursor;
        }
        private ContentResolver mContent;        
    }
```

For Simplicity I have created getMeaning() method in my DatabaseHelper class which returns desired results based on String in MultiAutoCompleteTextView:

In DBHelper Class,

```
public Cursor getMeaning(String searchString)
    {
        Cursor cursor=sqdb.query(MY_DB, new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_MEANING}, KEY_SEARCH+" like '"+searchString.toUpperCase()+"%'", null,null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Reference : http://hello-android.blogspot.com/2011/06/using-autocompletetextview-with-sqlite.html

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be to do your own  ArrayAdapter adapter. 
And in that adapter check what the string value is, if it is ie TY then add "Thank you".

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html check out EfficientAdapter. Or google custom ArrayAdapter, just make your a ArrayAdapter<String>

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to attach acronym and full strings something like Thank You - TY in the String array. This way autocomplete can recognize it when you type acronym too. Once the word is selected by the user, you can remove the part after hyphen '-'.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I already know your logic for this. But i dont want to go by this way. Coz it will unnecessarily recognize the other items having 'ty' for example///